# Search in text for column of words and return the word that matches

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two columns of data, the first (Column A) contains a whole load of text, the second (Column C) contains the "key" data.

I want to see if the text in Column A is matched by any of the entries in Column C. In Column B, I want the matching value shown, or if there is no match, "Not There". How can I do this?

Example attached.

```
Whole     Col  B    Key Data
123bob123    bob        sdf
124bob1246   bob        jim
a1225-ascon  ascon      ascon
256/sdf//abs sdf        bert
999bert999   bert       bob
```

Any assistance that anyone can offer will be very gratefully received. The grey matter is hurting....

Comment: Look into `vlookup`

Comment: Are you wanting _Column B_ to contain (in order) `[bob bob ascon sdf bert]` ?  If so, I don't think vlookup is going to do it.  What result would you expect if a row in _Column A_ contained `df32bob4/5bert33`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8313919/657668